# R data.table transform with row explosion

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to split one row into two (or more) rows when the cumsum of one of the column *breaks* the period.
Is there any elegant way to perform such specific row *explosion* using data.table?
Do not focus on cumsum (which I used in reversed order to have cumsum from most recent row to the oldest one), strictly speaking I want transform **dt** into **rdt** from code below.

```
# current data
dt <- data.table(
  time_id = 101:110, 
  desc = c('asd','qwe','xyz','qwe','qwe','xyz','asd','asd','qwe','asd'),
  value = c(5.5,3.5,14,0.7,6,5.5,9.3,29.8,4,7.2)
)
dt[, cum_value_from_now := rev(cumsum(rev(value)))]
period_width <- 10
dt[, value_period := ceiling(cum_value_from_now/period_width)*period_width]
dt

# expected result
rdt <- data.table(
  time_id = c(101,102,103,103,104,105,105,106,107,107,108,108,108,108,109,109,110), 
  desc = c('asd','qwe','xyz','xyz','qwe','qwe','qwe','xyz','asd','asd','asd','asd','asd','asd','qwe','qwe','asd'),
  value = c(5.5,3.5,6.5,7.5,0.7,1.8,4.2,5.5,0.3,9,1,10,10,8.8,1.2,2.8,7.2)
)[, cum_value_from_now := rev(cumsum(rev(value)))][, value_period := ceiling(cum_value_from_now/period_width)*period_width]
rdt

# validation
all.equal(
  dt[,list(time_id,desc,value)],
  rdt[,list(value = sum(value)), by=c('time_id','desc')]
  )
```

**edit:** I realized my question is not explained well the transformation I want to perform. To better understand the *breaks the period* meaning please take a look at my `rdt` the `cum_value_from_now` values from the last to first. Each `value_period` is completely filled by `cumsum` on `value`, the rest of `value` is produced as new row (if `value` is big enough then it is produced to multiple rows) to fit into next period(s). Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks the period" ?  Have some sympathy for us:  post a small, reproducible example using just a matrix, no `data.table` operations, and the desired outcome.  Equally useful: tell us what the point of this function is, as there may be a much simpler way to achieve your final goal.

Comment: "breaks the period" is best defined by `value_period` variable. It is kind of grouping variable, in this example grouping cumsum by `10`. As for the `matrix` example, I didn't use matrix for quite long time already and what I remember it might be not possible to mix data types in matrix. In my real `data.table` I use also more complex data types so it would be even harder to convert it to matrix. The point is to split rows which would fit to the two (or more) periods into multiple rows which would aggregate to the source row - as in the validation step.

Answer (score 1):

First, you seem to be applying your rules inconsistently. If "breaking the period" means that a row has `value_period` different from the previous row, then row 2 breaks the period, but you do not treat it that way.

Second, you never explain the partitioning of value. For instance, row 3 has `value=14`. This is replaced in `rdt` with two rows with values 6.5 and 7.5. These add to 14 all right, but there is no explanation of why this should be 6.5 and 7.5, rather than, say, 7 and 7. So in the solution below I partition equally.

The code below produces a result which passes your test, but it is not quite the same as your `rdt`, due to the above-mentioned problems with your question.

```
dt[,diff:=c(-diff(value_period)/10,0)]
rdt <- dt[,list(value=as.numeric(rep(value/(diff+1),diff+1))),
          by=list(time_id,desc,cum_value_from_now, value_period)]

all.equal(
  dt[,list(time_id,desc,value)],
  rdt[,list(value = sum(value)), by=c('time_id','desc')]
)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.
ad. 1st, please take a look at my `rdt` the `cum_value_from_now` values from the last to first. Each `value_period` is completely filled, the rest of value is produced as new row to fit into next period.
ad. row 3, it is being split to 6.5 and 7.5 to precisely fill the period. Split to 7,7 would produce rows which do not fill the periods, still slightly (by 0.5) exceeds it.
ad. code below, recalc the `cum_value_from_now` on your rdt to see it is not fitting the periods.
I hope my explanation was clear enough, looking forward for an update to your answer.Thanks in advance